# Can't access kibana with domain

Tags: kibana, elk

I generated certs for my app using `certbot/Letsencrypt`. I got two `pem` files which I added in my `kibana.yml` file. When I try to access kibana through https://domainName:5601 I get timeout error, while I can access it with IP. Am I missing something?

This is my `kibana.yml`:

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0.0.0.0"

server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate: "/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/fullchain.pem"
server.ssl.key: "/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/privkey.pem"
```

Comment: Did you tried to ping the domain, can it resolve to your IP?

Comment: `server.publicBaseUrl` could you try this?

Comment: @HùngPhạmViệt I tried adding the property, but I get `ValidationError: child "server" fails because ["publicBaseUrl" is not allowed].`. I've also tried adding the `server.basePath` and `server.rewriteBasePath`

Comment: The solution for this issue is here : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-server-publicbaseurl/293661

Answer (score 4):

If you upgraded with the latest version i.e. 7.x then u need to add `server.publicBaseUrl` in your `kibana.yml`

for e.g. `server.publicBaseUrl=xyz.com`

so it will allow you to redirect your website.

For me it is working fine after adding this parameter inside `kibana.yml`

Comment: The suggested setting will not be accepted by Kibana - it needs a protocol or you get `FATAL  Error: [config validation of [server].publicBaseUrl]: expected URI with scheme [http|https].`